# Find records which cross-reference each other

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to extract all the rows from a database table, where the rows cross-reference each other.

My table contains 2 rows: `ref1` & `ref2`

Table example:

```
ID  ref1  ref2
01    23    83
02    77    55
03    83    23
04    13    45
```

In this case, I want my query to return only rows 01 and 03, because they cross-reference each other.

Is this possible using a single query, or will I need to iterate the entire table manually?

I'm using MySQL.

Comment: Just to clarify, you just want straight cross references, not circular references involving more rows?

Comment: Yes, only straight cross-references.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple JOIN can do that in a straight forward manner;

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM mytable a
JOIN mytable b
  ON a.ref1 = b.ref2 AND a.ref2 = b.ref1;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1980fe/2).

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    *
from
    tbl t1
where
    exists (
        select
            'x'
        from
            tbl t2
        where
            t1.ref1 = t2.ref2 and
            t1.ref2 = t2.ref1
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted the other answer, which was slightly simpler.

Comment: @user3950463 you haven't selected any answer yet please read [*`Accepting Answers: How does it work?`*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Let me first present the solution in a context of a table that is meant for representing trees but faces this issue (resulting in a cross reference that is not anymore part of the tree).

Note: If your root tree record(s) reference themselves then you need to filter them out ( `a.id!=b.id`) as below, to keep only cross-referencing records.

```sql
-- case of a tree(s)
select 
  a.id currentId, 
  b.id parentId, 
  b.parent_id grandParentId 
from my_table a 
join my_table b on 
  a.parent_id=b.id 
  and b.parent_id=a.id 
  and a.id!=b.id;
```

Now in your case, the above query can be written as (Again considering that records referencing themselves are allowed we add `and a.ref1!=b.ref2`):

```sql
-- case of a graph(s)
select 
  a.ref1 theCurrent, 
  b.ref1 theRef, 
  b.ref2 theRefsRef 
from my_table a 
join my_table b on 
  a.ref2=b.ref1 
  and b.ref2=a.ref1 
  and a.ref1!=b.ref2;
```